# how to end the of the ruler (vertical line) at the end of a twocolumn document?

Tags: two-column

If a vertical ruler is visible, it also extends to the end of the last page of the document, even if there are no contents. How  can I ensure the vertical line only reaches where contents are available?

Here is an example. I would love to see the vertical line only reaches the bottom of the texts.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.01cm}


\title{XXX}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

These are some test texts.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Without knowing what you are doing we cannot give any advice. Please post the code of a compilable document that shows your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use package `multicol` instead of `twocolumn` option for article class. The last page will have the two columns balanced, and the vertical rule will extend only to the lenght of these columns:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.01cm}


\title{XXX}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]